# "undefined reference to" errors in my cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, eigen3, unittest++

I'm having a bit of trouble organizing [my c++ project](https://github.com/tbrown122387/markets) as a cmake project, which is something I'm new to. I'm trying to mimic the template given by [this github repository](https://github.com/kigster/cmake-project-template). I think I'm almost there, but I'm getting a few linker errors when I try to compile with the following commands:

```
cd markets
rm -rf build/manual
mkdir build/manual
cd build/manual
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-8 ../..
make
```

There's a lot of output, but here are the first few lines:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable markets_tests
CMakeFiles/markets_tests.dir/src/test_data_handler.cpp.o: In function `Testtest_data_handler::RunImpl() const':
test_data_handler.cpp:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `Instrument::Instrument(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
test_data_handler.cpp:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `Instrument::Instrument(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
test_data_handler.cpp:(.text+0x37f): undefined reference to `DataHandler::DataHandler(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, unsigned int const&, unsigned int const&)'
CMakeFiles/markets_tests.dir/src/test_data_reader.cpp.o: In function `Testtest_csv_reader::RunImpl() const':
test_data_reader.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `csv_reader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned int)'
```

I guess this must mean that something is wrong with my `markets/test/CMakeLists.txt` file, which I have now as:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(markets_tests)


find_package(UnitTest++ REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-no-pie")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

include_directories(${MARKETS_HEADERS_DIR})
include_directories(${UTPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp 
         src/test_data_handler.cpp
         src/test_data_reader.cpp
         src/test_exec_handler.cpp
         src/test_fill.cpp
         src/test_instrument.cpp
         src/test_market_bar.cpp
         src/test_market_snapshot.cpp
         src/test_order.cpp
         src/test_pnl_calculator.cpp
         src/test_portfolio.cpp
         src/test_position_summary.cpp) 

add_executable(markets_tests ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(markets_tests markets Eigen3::Eigen UnitTest++)  # added Eigen
install(TARGETS markets_tests DESTINATION bin)
```

Any ideas? Other questions seem to suggest that I could be linking things in the wrong order, but this project structure isn't that complicated (just an executable, a library, and some unit tests). This was compiling with my old makefile, so I doubt it's because I haven't defined some of the header definitions.

Here is the `tree` of my `markets/` root directory if it helps:

```
.
├── bin
├── build
│   └── manual
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── docs
├── lib
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── markets
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── data_handlers.cpp
│       ├── data_handlers.h
│       ├── data_readers.cpp
│       ├── data_readers.h
│       ├── execution_handler.cpp
│       ├── execution_handler.h
│       ├── fill.cpp
│       ├── fill.h
│       ├── instrument.cpp
│       ├── instrument.h
│       ├── market_bar.cpp
│       ├── market_bar.h
│       ├── market_snapshot.cpp
│       ├── market_snapshot.h
│       ├── order.cpp
│       ├── order.h
│       ├── pnl_calculator.cpp
│       ├── pnl_calculator.h
│       ├── portfolio.cpp
│       ├── portfolio.h
│       ├── position_summary.cpp
│       └── position_summary.h
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── src
    │   ├── test_data_handler.cpp
    │   ├── test_data_reader.cpp
    │   ├── test_exec_handler.cpp
    │   ├── test_fill.cpp
    │   ├── test_instrument.cpp
    │   ├── test_market_bar.cpp
    │   ├── test_market_snapshot.cpp
    │   ├── test_order.cpp
    │   ├── test_pnl_calculator.cpp
    │   ├── test_portfolio.cpp
    │   └── test_position_summary.cpp
    └── test_data
        ├── QLD.csv
        └── SPY.csv
```

### Edit:

Here is `src/markets/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(markets)### C CXX)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    data_handlers.h
    data_handlers.cpp
    data_readers.h
    data_readers.cpp
    execution_handler.h
    execution_handler.cpp
    fill.h
    fill.cpp
    instrument.h
    instrument.cpp
    market_bar.h
    market_bar.cpp
    market_snapshot.h
    market_snapshot.cpp
    order.h
    order.cpp
    pnl_calculator.h
    pnl_calculator.cpp
    portfolio.h
    portfolio.cpp
    position_summary.h
    position_summary.cpp
)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
add_library(markets SHARED STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(markets Eigen3::Eigen stdc++fs) #added this

install(TARGETS markets DESTINATION ${MARKETS_INSTALL_LIB_DIR})
install(FILES markets.h DESTINATION ${MARKETS_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Comment: One problem is probably in the `src/markets/CMakeLists.txt` file, where you probably forgot to add some source files when building the library. You also seem to be missing the file where `csv_reader` is implemented (or just haven't defined (implemented) it).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I've got everything in there. I just added a display of it to the question. `csv_reader` is in `data_readers.h`

Comment: Having `__cxx11` in the missed symbols smells like you have `market` library, which contains given symbols, compiled with true C++11 standard, but your current project is compiled with pre-C++11 (that is why it uses `__cxx11` namespace). Try to add `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` into `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I used `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` in the root `CMakeLists.txt` file, which I believe is required because I'm using the newer `filesystem` library

Comment: Reduce your project to a [mre] and post all relevant parts here (do not link to an external resource). You may even find your error yourself after reducing your project to something smaller.

Comment: Have you defined (implemented) a `Instrument` constructor taking a `std::string const&` argument? That's one of the complaints.

Comment: Placing before the `project()` call  setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` has no effect. I guess the same is about `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`. (You **actually** have `__cxx11` symbols linked, so the *used* standard is definitely not a c++17.). You definitely need to post all relevant parts of the code in the question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The `11` in that namespace name only says that GCC is using a new ABI introduced in GCC 5 *and later*. The actual C++ version used is irrelevant, it could be C++11, C++14 or C++17. See e.g. [this GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_dual_abi.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks! It seems that I understood meaning of `__cxx11` incorrectly. But nevertheless, having such namespace in the "undefined reference" error message usually signals about ABI incompatibility (between created executable and linked library).

Comment: this might be annoying, but I fixed it by deleting these `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` I had defined earlier